# Model for supervised learning on graphs with varying structure

Tags: r, regression, graphical-model, image-processing, graph-theory

Colorization problem is considered.

[image: Colorization example]

I have a training set of unordered graphs (images) with varying number of vertices and edges (color regions and adjacency between them, resp.).
[image]

A fixed number of features is associated with each vertex (color, area, etc.) and with each edge (length of common border, color contrast, etc.).

For input graph (an image to be colored) the trained model is supposed to specify color for each vertex (color region) of the input graph.

Classic regression algorithms (svm, decision trees, etc.) take fixed sized vectors as input and return fixed sized vectors.

Is there a model that naturally handles varying number of vertices / edges?

Is there an approach to adapt fixed structure models (MRF, factor graphs, etc.) to handle this particular case?

Comment: The first image is from «[Probabilistic Color-by-Numbers: Suggesting Pattern Colorizations Using Factor Graphs](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/patternColoring.html)» where authors present a probabilistic factor graph model for automatically coloring 2D patterns. Unfortunately their approach is limited by fixed size of color palette.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35675840/1682275) several papers on graph-based learning are listed.

Comment: I moved your post to a comment because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @whuber No, it does.

Comment: According to the standards of this site, a link-only answer is not an answer.  Links are fine provided they are accompanied by effective descriptions or summaries of their contents.